# Trouble with stored procedure for deleting least recent entries in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

The query I have written is:

```
delete from featured where featuredID IN(
select top(@removeAmnt) * from featured 
order by featured.createdon asc)
```

which doesn't appear to work. The error I get is, "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.". I'm not to familiar with sql queries. I'm basically trying to order these by their createdon field who's default value is the date function. also, the the sp allows a value removeAmnt to be passed in, which is the # of table entries that will be selected from the top to be deleted.

Comment: please define "doesn't appear to work".  does it mean no rows are deleted? the wrong rows are deleted, or something else?

Comment: This is a good article about doing a top with a variable amount of rows. http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-a-top-clause-in-sql-server.html

Comment: when you do where column in (select ....) you should only select that column, so remove your "*" in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most likely you need to remove the `*`:

```
delete from featured where featuredID IN(
select top(@removeAmnt) featuredID  from featured 
order by featured.createdon asc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what result you are getting but your select in the in clause shouldn't be * but featuredID.

```
delete from featured 
where featuredID IN(
                    select top(@removeAmnt) featured.featuredid from featured 
                    order by featured.createdon as
                    )
```